# Probability of a coin falling on the edges of a square

Tags: probability, random-variables, geometric-probability

Let a coin be randomly (and uniformly) dropped onto a square on the floor. Assume the edge length of the square to be $ d $ and the radius of the coin to be $ r < d/4$. I know that the probability of the coin avoiding the edges is given by the ratio of the area of a smaller square of edge length $ d - 2r $ inside the larger one to the area of the larger square, i.e. $$ p = \frac{(d-2r)^2}{d^2} $$
But is the probability of it falling on the edges just $ 1-p $ ? If we translate that back into areas, wouldn't that mean the centre of the coin can fall only in a certain band of width $ r $ around the edge but **only on the inside of the larger square**? Shouldn't we consider the case when the centre of the coin can lie outside but still cross the edges? i.e., it can lie in a band of width $ r $ on the outside of the larger square as well? So, is the probability then $$ q = \frac{(d+r)^2-(d-r)^2}{(d+r)^2} $$ I want to know if the sample space is correct. Is it $(d+r)^2 $ or $d^2$? And why isn't $p+q=1$? I know $q$ is most probably wrong; please correct me.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the sentence "Let a coin be randomly (and uniformly) dropped onto a square on the floor". This is Buffon sort of thing. It is good that you are asking such questions. Too few people think about the details.

Comment: These Buffon-needle-type problems typically assume an infinite *grid* of squares (or parallel lines, or whatever), so that the center of the randomly dropped object is guaranteed to fall inside *some* square.

Comment: @BarryCipra Oh! So if I have just one square instead of a grid, would the probability of the coin falling on an edge be $0$? If not what would the probability of it be?

Comment: @camagnussen, as copper.hat says, it depends on how you interpret the opening sentence.  I'm guessing that the *intended* interpretation is that the *center* of the coin lands randomly, with uniform probability, *inside* the square.  (That's what assuming an infinite grid effectively achieves.)

Comment: How do you “know” $p$? Wherever you got that information, it should have explained what the assumptions were that allowed computing $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered.

As noted in the comments, it all depends on what you mean by the first sentence. The calculation is correct if the first sentence is meant to say that the centre of the coin is uniformly randomly selected inside the square. There's no uniform distribution over the entire plane; "uniformly randomly selected" always requires a domain of finite measure to be specified.